# Laravel eloquent pluck() method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get id of product where designation matches the `$request->designation`.
Here is my code:

```
Product::where('designation', $product)->pluck('id');
```

but it return both the product and it id but i just need the id of the product.
How can i solve this?

Comment: it did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The **`pluck()`** method will return instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. You should try chaining **`toArray()`** as follow to get the desired result in array format.

```php
Product::where('designation', $product)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

The `pluck()` method chained with `toArray()` will return array of product ids.
**The pluck method is not supposed to return the object itself along with id, so the behavior you've got is exceptional.** If you have any additional information, it can help to solve the issue. I've tried this and git the desired result.

[image: The Code]
[image: result]

> Using `value()` is another option but it has its own drawbacks. The value() method queries the framework queries the database, hydrates the model, and then returns only that value. You can save yourself a few keystrokes and few CPU cycles by using `pluck()` and have it handled simply in one query.

Comment: here is `dd()` of the query using `value()` : `array:2 [
  0 => "Couteau"
  1 => 1
] ` and here is the `dd()` with `pluck()` chained wiht `toArray()` : `array:2 [
  0 => "Couteau"
  1 => array:1 [
    0 => 1
  ]
]` but i want to get only `1 => 1` or  `1 => array:1 [
    0 => 1
  ]`

Comment: check your table, there must be an id field containing the value `Couteau`. I assume that you have the wrong data and datatype in the table maybe. because both the `pluck` and `value` methods work well. The above-given code snippet has been tested so many times.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `value()` function instead.

```php
Product::where('designation', $product)->value('id');
```

Comment: @A.Rahman `Product::where('designation', $product)->value('id');` should give you the single value